# iOS Sprite Animation Frame Rate

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am making "yet another iOS" game with cocos2d and am now wondering what an acceptable number of frames per second for sprite animation would suffice?

This is more of a theoretical question as to how many animation frames I have to draw in order for the game to look good. For example: an animation specialist would love to draw 32 frames for a second of animation, whereas I think 4 frames is really enough. I do not wish to sacrifice RAM for something that no one might even notice. So what is the best number of frames to draw for a second of sprite animation? 4,6,8,12,16,20,24,32?

**Update:** If I create high-res graphics for the new iPad then then a single sprite animation of 24 Frames does not fit inside a Texture Atlas of 2048x2048 pixels :( and I do not want to have a lot of these out of concers for RAM. Or am I thinking something very wrong here in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The human eye and its brain interface, the human visual system, can process 10 to 12 separate images per second, perceiving them individually.

[<sup><sup><sup>[Source]</sup></sup></sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate#Background)

So I would consider something higher than this to ensure your animation is perceived smoothly.

For reasons I'm not really sure of, I want to suggest multiples of these numbers, so I usually go for **24fps** for **character animations** and often much less, down to perhaps **6fps** for **a fireball (for example)**

However when it comes down to it, I haven't really noticed a slowdown from running animations at higher speeds. You might do well to measure the time it takes to update at different frame rates.

---

Comment: Well, if I create high-res graphics for the new iPad then then a single sprite animation of 24 Frames does not fit inside a Texture Atlas of 2048x2048 pixels :( and I do not want to have a lot of these out of concers for RAM. Or am I thinking something very wrong here in the first place?

Comment: I devised a way of dramatically cutting down the artwork required for animations by reusing art. e.g. only having one head and moving it between the different positions in each frame for example. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936003/converting-flash-animation-to-cocos2d) for more information. I did use *flash* for the animation, but the concept should be the same if you can find something similar for your situation

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the most important thing to say here is:

> This matter will NOT be essential for the success of your game

Whatever frame rate the human eye can see or not, if you are making a 2D-game for iOS what matters the most is that the game is fun to play, looks cool and plays smoothly. Focus on that.

*Start out with a number of frames for your animations that makes it simple and convenient for you to develop* (i.e. not too much work, no worries about sizes) You will see when you play your game if it looks good or not, don't worry. And if it don't, the problem may not be the amount of frames, but what content your frames illustrate in the particular movement.

As for the physical discussion, 24 fps was the format chosen for movies because it was thought that the eye could not make a distinction since it catches about 12 frames per second. It has however turned out that it is possible to see difference between video material shown in 24 fps and materials shown in higher framerate. The reason for this is that the human brain is smart and can not be tricked by the illusion.

However my opinion is that this discussion is for filmmakers, not 2d-game makers. 24fps for animations is most likely a huge overkill. People don't have nearly the same expectations on a game that is played on a small screen. They will focus on playability, smoothness and general feeling and awesomeness. If you are making a 3d-game the animations are calculated by the 3d engine by interpolation on-the fly, thus the animations can (in theory) be up to 60fps (or whatever the fps of the game is). In 2d I would never expect anything more than what makes sense for the development process.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the FPS goes, I used 15FPS in my own iPhone app and it works just fine and looks good without using much CPU time or disk space. Just find the right value for your needs and then do not worry about it anymore. Use of a Texture Atlas for your animation needs is a real issue. If you use lots and lots of very small textures and the animation loops are very small (meaning one atlas contains the entire animation cycle) then you will benefit from an Atlas (see [optimizing-texture-atlases](http://www.appsizematters.com/2011/04/optimizing-texture-atlases/)). But, once your animations get to a certain size (in width x height or duration) then you would be better off just using a video format with alpha channel support (for example, see [displaying-animations-in-opengl](http://jacobeiting.tumblr.com/post/31268148559/displaying-animations-in-opengl-on-ios-using-bink-and)). If you want to read about the approach I suggest, please have a look at [Load OpenGL textures with alpha channel on iOS](http://iosgraphicsanimation.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/load-opengl-textures-with-alpha-channel-on-ios/) for source code of an Xcode project that implements loading of OpenGL textures from a movie file with alpha channel support.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't necessarily come down to a number of frames but to smoothness. The human eye doesn't have a frame rate as much as it is susceptible to changes, even quick ones.

James' answer is correct in that anything less than 12 frames per second is usually seen as choppy. Instead of trying to avoid choppiness by aiming for a sufficiently high number, try out several different rates and pick the one that most people think is still smooth but that has the frame rate that fits your budget. (Obviously you also have to factor in e.g. the pacing of your character's movement.)

Additionally, things that are ornamental or less important don't have to have as many frames. Choosing a good lowest common denominator for the frame rate keeps this from looking weird.